# ASP.NET MVC - jquery datepicker - Link to view

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker

i want to have a link with the choosen date to click at the datepicker
e.g:

```
 <div type="text" id="datepicker"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#datepicker").datepicker({ <a href="/controller/view/" /> });
     });
```

After I clicked i want to be at follwing adress: /controller/view/20091212

Is something with datepicker possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the onSelect event:

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({onSelect: openday});




  function openday(dateText, inst) {

            window.location = 'controller/action/' + encodeURIComponent(dateText);
  }
```